# Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred?

Tags: rx-swift

"Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred" - this error comes as I write guard statement - what is inside guard statement which causes error that element could not be inferred.

```
static func makeTokenForCard(with cardinfo: CardInfo) -> Single<String> {
return Single.create { 
    single in guard let ck = try CheckoutKit.getInstance("pk_123456789876543234567, env: Environment.SANDBOX, debug: true) 
    else {
        let descr = "Unexpectedly Checkout got invalid private key. You may need to update the app."
        single(.error(NSError.recreate(error: CheckoutError.invalidPK as NSError, description: descr)))
        return
        }
        single(.success("123456"))
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

When I remove this Guard statement - it returns simple String and errors in Single.

Edit :

After getting more into error, I found that its due to throws.

```
open class func getInstance(_ pk: String, env: Environment, debug: Bool) throws -> CheckoutKit? {
```

In Simple Guard & wrapping its fine.

So, How to call a method in Single when it has throws some expected error
?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't RxSwift related but more Swift and handling errors. 
The simplest answer to your question is to use `try?` instead `try`. This will fix the issue.

You can read more about error handling here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: I put try block inside do catch - & it worked. Thanks.